# When does combat begin and end during a dungeon?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, movement, time

I am a first-timer trying to prepare to host my first D&D night as DM with a bunch of curious friends (also first-timers in roleplaying).

I got the Starter Set so I'll be trying to play the *Lost Mine of Phandelver* campaign. After reading the *Starter Set Rulebook* and the first chapter of the campaign book, I find myself wondering about turns and time.

Are there still turns between encounters inside a dungeon? Are the player characters limited by their speed while moving in the dungeon out of combat?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! If the linked question and answer do not answer your question please [edit] your question to explain how you think they are different and to focus your question on the parts that you are interested in.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.